# Softwares like Blazemeter which record website action to create .jmx files

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

What other software is there like Blazemeter Chrome Plugin which can be used to record website action and create a .jmx script to run on JMeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all there is JMeter's built-in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [BadBoy tool](http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/jmeter.htm) can export recordings as JMeter .jmx files
3. [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder (Mobile And Web)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-) automates certificate installation procedures and is capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" format with automated correlation applied